# How find the occurrences of same value in different columns using a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I was attending an interview I have faced an interesting question, which is listed below
The question is given below

> How to find out the occurrence of the value 1 in all the columns

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,1,3)
```

I have shared the answer like below. Not sure whether this is a proper answer.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @tbl WHERE COL1 = 1) +
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @tbl WHERE COL2 = 1)+
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @tbl WHERE COL3 = 1)
```

Please let me know whether is there any other way to find out the proper answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select cols, count(*) as occurrence 
from @tbl cross apply 
     ( values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), ('col3', col3)
     ) t (cols, val)
where val = 1
group by cols;
```

Comment: Great .. Wonderful:)

Comment: Great answer (upvote from my side). One backdraw: You still have to know (and type) the column's names...

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing an answer came in my mind:) Don't know how far it is correct.

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,1,3)
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Col1 =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN Col3 =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM @tbl WHERE (Col1 = 1 OR Col2 =1 OR COl3=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECt a.*, b.x  FROM @tbl a
OUTER APPLY
(   
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM (VALUES(a.Col1),(a.Col2),(a.Col3)) c(a)
    WHERE   
        c.a = 1
) b(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more approach uses the great abilities of XML and `XQuery` to deal with generic data. It will be fully generic when you pass in the value as `sql:column()` or `sql:variable` instead of the hardcoded "1". This approach would not even need to know the count and names of the columns in advance:

```
DECLARE @tbl AS TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,1,3);
```

--Find a row where all values are 1

```sql
SELECT 
(
    SELECT * FROM @tbl FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('tbl'),TYPE
)
.query('/tbl/row[not(*/text()!="1")]');
```

--Count the 1s

```sql
SELECT *
      ,x.value('count(/row/*[text()="1"])','int')
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE) AS A(x)
```

Comment: Now i have to also start with xml.